# How to access single columns in pandas for loop?

Tags: python, pandas

I've a column which has ratings like "4.1/5" I want to remove the slash (/) and it is a object type. I want to convert it to float so I'm trying to create a function to do that.

Please correct me what I'm doing wrong. I'm trying something like

```
def remove_slash_from_rating(ratings):
    for i in ratings:
        df[rate] = df[rate].str.replace(r'/','')
```

But when I'm imputing it (df["rate"] = df["rate"].apply(remove_slash_from_rating)) then I'm getting an error

```
NameError: name 'rate' is not defined
```

Please check the above post

Comment: there is a typo: it should be df["rate"] = df["rate"]...  in your example.  Anyhow, the solution from jezrael is better.

Comment: replace will just produce eg 4.15; if the intention is to produce a float value eg. 0.82 then you could use .str.extract (which uses normal regex formats) to give both the numerator and denominator in new columns and then divide the two to give your float.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no loop, no `apply` necessary, use [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) for column `rate`:

```
df["rate"] = df["rate"].str.replace(r'/','')
```